# Connecting to server which located remotely throws timeout exception

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, remote

Below are the steps which I follow while connecting manually:

1. Connect to VPN
2. RDP to the remote machine using my credentials
3. Open SQL Server Management Studio
4. Connect to Server > database engine, Server Name > "Name", Authentication >  Windows Authentication
5. Run query

And the connection string that I am using is:

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source =tcp:<IPAddress of RDP Machine>\<ServerName>;
Initial Catalog =<DBName>; User Id = <Username>; 
Password = <Password>; Trusted_Connection = True; 
Integrated Security = SSPI; Connect Timeout = 30; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = False"
```

Comment: So the manual query via SSMS works, right? What is using the connection string? It seems to miss a lot of data; is it anonymized?

Answer (score 2):

In your manual procedure you state that you specify "name" in the server name, not an instance.

However in your connection string you specify

```
Data Source =tcp:<IPAddress of RDP Machine>\<ServerName>;
```

Which indicates `<servername>` should be used as an instance name.

You should probably remove `\<servername>` part of your connection string.

You should also verify the necessary ports are open on the firewall and make sure [SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) as well as make sure [tcp/ip is in the enabled protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017).

There is a decent MSDN blog post covering a lot of other steps you can take to troubleshoot your connectivity issues: [Troubleshoot Connectivity/Login failures (18456 State x) with SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/02/06/troubleshoot-connectivitylogin-failures-18456-state-x-with-sql-server/)